# nginx reload doesn't work, but restart does

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I installed on a new server with Ubuntu 18.04 Nginx mainline, current version nginx/1.15.6

Whichever way I try to reload nginx, it gives no error but it doesn't work, the configuration isn't reloaded:

```
# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# 
# service nginx reload
# /etc/init.d/nginx reload
[ ok ] Reloading nginx configuration (via systemctl): nginx.service.
# nginx -s reload
# systemctl reload nginx
```

If I do `restart` instead, it works but with some seconds of downtime that I want to avoid. 
What could be the issue?

Comment: can you elaborate on what change is being made in the nginx config that reloading doesn't work on?

Comment: any change I made isn't applied, for example I changed `try_files $uri $uri/ =404;` to `try_files $uri $uri/ =418;` and opened a random nonexistent page, it's still 404 until I restart nginx

Comment: when you reload do you see multiple nginx processes running? Reload works mostly in the same way a restart does, but there are a few cases where a restart is required to get the changes to load. A reload will leave the old process to terminate gracefully while bringing up the new process. You can note the PID of the old process, reload and see if you have only a new PID or both the old and new.

Comment: no, `ps aux | grep nginx` shows that all the processes started many days ago, when I did nginx restart

Comment: there is one `[nginx] <defunct>` and many `nginx: worker process is shutting down`

Comment: a weird thing is that there are 40 master processes...

Comment: what is your worker_processes set to in the config? This determines how many master processes get spun up.

Comment: I suspect you have multiple copies of nginx running which have escaped notice of systemd somehow. I suggest killing every copy of nginx running, then restarting nginx. If there are still any zombie processes, as  you showed in your comment, then just restart the computer.

Comment: I had it recently on a replication server with about 100 services. sudo nginx -s reload wouldn't be sufficient, nginx would redirect some of the new services I put in place to the default (as if nginx didn't see my new config files). Doing a sudo service nginx restart did fix that though.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC nginx asks its worker threads to restart soon when you send a reload - and with HTTP/2 it can take a while for the threads to recycle (they wait until they are idle).

> it works but with some seconds of downtime

Erk, I'm running approx 200 sites behind my nginx proxies and it takes about half a second to do a restart on each one.

Comment: I have between 6 and 9k active connections (not proxied but php-fpm directly) and it takes many seconds, since my clients want 100% uptime I cannot afford a down, but you're right about the first part, you just need to wait